# Angular HTTP observables behave differently compared to regular observables?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

While I was messing with routing in Angular, I tried using an in memory database to fetch the heroes.

The original StackBlitz is https://stackblitz.com/angular/yoerxnmrbod

If you go to the heroes tab, click on a hero, and change his name, the change is reflected in the list.

I changed how the data is backed to be the angular in memory database.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ke7pxn-vxp9hi?file=src/app/app.module.ts

If you follow the same workflow as the above, the name change in the details component isn't reflected in the list.  What am I missing to get the same functionality?

Comment: You aren't provisioning the service or calling createDb().  It looks like it's not complete.

Comment: @chrispy Which service?  I followed the barebones of what was needed to get the in memory database to work.  I didn't do any of the logging and such because it seemed superfluous for what I'm trying to show.  This is what I based the example from. https://stackblitz.com/angular/ybbpegbnnlq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the reason is when you set HEROES as const in hero.service and then pass a separate hero and change his name, the name is changed in your HEROES array element (because it's an array of objects, and even if it is const, it's elements and their properties can be changed). And in the second realization, you always get a new instance of heroes array. If you want to save some changes to it, you should store it in your service and use like a simple array (without async pipe) and not receive it from your mock-backend each time.